# How can I connect without entering the ssh login password?

Tags: ssh, gnupg

`gpg -d -q .sshpass.gpg | xargs -i sshpass {} ssh -tt user@server`

`root@localhost:~# ^[[A^[[C^C`

I thought I was going to connect to an interactive shell.

However, only the prompt from the remote server is displayed.
Since nothing was input, I had no choice but to escape with ctrl+c.

I expected to be able to log in via ssh with an encrypted password.

I often connect to multiple servers via ssh.
I am trying to use ssh connection by registering it as an alias.
Is there another way?

Comment: Try adding `-o` (open TTY) for `xargs`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you favour connecting with a password over using public key authentication?

Comment: Thank you for your comment
This is because we thought it would be difficult to register the authentication key on many servers. One of the reasons is that the number of management servers increases and decreases.

Comment: `gpg -d -q .sshpass.gpg | xargs -io sshpass {} ssh -tt user@server`
ssh: Could not resolve hostname da[password]u: Name or service not known
xargs: sshpass: exited with status 255; aborting

Comment: `man xargs` : _-i[replace-str] This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is specified._. In your `xargs -io ...` invocation, "o" is understood as being the "replace-str" placeholder. Instead try `xargs -o -i ...`

Comment: `gpg -d -q .sshpass.gpg | xargs -o -i sshpass -p {} ssh -tt user@server`
It was successful. Thank you very much.